# an adjective for a person who is so lazy that he is willing to lie

Tags: выбор-слова

What adjective in Russian would best describe a policeman who is deliberately twisting some facts in the protocol in order to close the case as soon as possible because he is too lazy to deal with it in a due manner?

I thought of "корумпированный" and "продажный", but these two seem to imply doing something illegal for money, that is, for bribes, but in my case bribes are not involved.

Another one that I considered was "нечистоплотный", but this one strikes me more like an adjective for a gambler involved in some game, while in my example it is not a game.

Perhaps, "недобросовестный" would fit the bill, but, as far as I know, this would mean that the policeman was not diligent enough, while in my case he is not only not diligent, that is, lazy, but is also willing to write lies in the report due to his laziness.

Comment: I doubt there is a 100% match for what you're looking for, but нерадивый might be close enough.

Comment: _Безалаберный_ (literally, disorganized, irresponsible) might work as well in that context. An example: https://en.hkcinema.ru/filmarticle/734 _Безалаберный полицейский Ма Ю-Лунг с большим трудом справляется со своими непосредственными обязанностями..._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

“*Недобросовестный*” is pretty good, but if you want to underline
the fact that he is *criminally* lazy and negligent, a better
word would be
“[*халатный*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/259834)”.
In fact, the Russian Criminal Code article about criminal negligence is
called
“[*УК РФ Ст. 293. Халатность*](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/33ed8a9caec9cd5b4c329b9a17409a19c583d4d4/)”.

Answer (score 0):

I do think he is inventive. or enterprising.no matter what the cause is. so I suggest хитромудрый or even(хитрожопый) in this case.